# Android API 31 - WorkManager - PendingIntent - flag IMMUTABLE error

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, flags, android-workmanager

**Exception**:
Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent

**Code causing the exception**:
WorkManager.getInstance(context).createCancelPendingIntent(id)

**build.gradle options**:

compileSdkVersion 31

buildToolsVersion '30.0.3' (version 31.0.0 gives error: Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager).

**Emulator**:
API 31 (with API S everything works fine)

**dependencies**:

// WorkManager

implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0-alpha05"

implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'

I think the problem could be in this method of **BuildCompat.java**:

```
/**
 * Checks if the device is running on a pre-release version of Android S or a release version of
 * Android S or newer.
 * <p>
 * <strong>Note:</strong> When Android S is finalized for release, this method will be
 * deprecated and all calls should be replaced with {@code Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=
 * Build.VERSION_CODES.S}.
 *
 * @return {@code true} if S APIs are available for use, {@code false} otherwise
 */
@ChecksSdkIntAtLeast(codename = "S")
public static boolean isAtLeastS() {
    return VERSION.CODENAME.equals("S");
}
```

That's because when I run the app on the emulator and log the version name I get:
version name: REL

Answer (score 6):

Based on [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194108978#comment5), it seems the fix is to add the dependency on `androidx.core:core:1.7.0-alpha01` which includes a fix for `BuildCompat.isAtLeastS()`.

> It looks like what you are missing is a dependency on the latest version of `android.core`. That includes [this](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1721011) change which has an important bug fix for `BuildCompat.isAtLeastS()`.

Comment: Yes, this was the fix. Thanks.

Comment: In my case this helped: `implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0'`, although I don't use WorkManager at all, but one of dependent libraries uses it.

Comment: worked for me as well - implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0'

Answer (score 1):

Set your pending intent as below

```js
val updatedPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
   applicationContext,
   NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE,
   updatedIntent,
   PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT // setting the mutability flag 
)
```

as per this doc

> https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#pending-intent-mutability