# I can't get rid of FLAG_IMMUTABLE and FLAG_MUTABLE pending intent flags error

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent

I am developing an android apploication in Android Studio.
When I run it on android version 30 and below everything works as expected.
But when I run it on version 31 and above (target S+), I get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-1
    Process: com.privileb.card, PID: 20926
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.privileb.card: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
        at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:401)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:671)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:658)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.getPendingIntent(ForceStopRunnable.java:273)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.isForceStopped(ForceStopRunnable.java:151)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.forceStopRunnable(ForceStopRunnable.java:171)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:102)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

I tried to get rid of every line that has `PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(...)` but **I keep getting the same error.**

Comment: The error says this is coming from `androidx.work`. What version of WorkManager are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is coming from the Workmanager AndroidX library, which [had a bug in earlier versions](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194108978). Upgrade to Workmanager 2.7.0 or newer to solve it per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68547548/1992342).